# What is the sql-puzzle tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across a question tagged [sql-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-puzzle) and couldn't find any indication as to whether it was a particular DBMS, some software, or what (the tag wiki is blank and nothing turned up on Google either). Next 3 questions in the tag all just seem to be sql issues that the OP finds puzzling, which is pretty much all questions on SO. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a useless tag that should be removed?

Also, I suppose, I'm hesitant to create a bunch of suggested edits to remove it, if someone with 2k+ rep wants to remove the tag.

Answer (score 16):

**All** posts that use it only use it to say they find the SQL puzzling. It is a meta tag and deserves to burn.

I have haz burninated it. With FIRE.

[image: tag burninated]

♫♩ Burninating the countryside ♪♬ burninating the peasants ♫♩ burninating all the peoples ♬♪ in the thatch roofed cottages! ♬♩

*Wicked dueling guitar-solos*.

Comment: Had to one up me with the image.... :(

Comment: Is it even a meta tag, or would it be like tagging every question [question]?

Comment: @Michelle: It describes the OP's state of mind, not the question. It is like tagging every question with `please-answer-this`.

Comment: @bluefeet: hey, I FGITW-ed you too! Give me *some* credit. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was too busy retagging to FGITW.  At least I could add `status-completed` - mod perk.

Comment: @bluefeet: I am jealous of that perk. I should totally run next election just for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You should, I've got no doubt you'd be a great mod.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why that tag exists.  It has been removed quickly and with fire!

This tag offers no benefit to anyone.  It will be purged during the nightly tag clean up.